# Scraping video duration - casperjs

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I am currently trying to scrape a video duration with the help of casperjs. The video is inside a div id `cne-player`. The duration value shows right after the page loads for this reason I found casperjs to be the best tool for the job. I am getting an empty value when scraping for the duration. Below is a snippet of the [SITE](http://video.wired.com/watch/battle-damage-iphone-6-plus-vs-galaxy-note-4) html infrastructure. How or what would be the way to retrieve the video duration?

JS

```
var casper = require('casper').create({}),durations;

function getDuration() {
    var element = document.querySelectorAll('.vjs-control');
    return Array.prototype.map.call(element, function(e) {
        result = e.textContent;
        return result.trim();
    });
}

casper.start('http://video.wired.com/watch/battle-damage-iphone-6-plus-vs-galaxy-note-4');

casper.then(function() {
    durations = this.evaluate(getDuration);
});

casper.run( this.echo(durations) );
```

HTML

```
<div id="cne-player">
    <div class="vjs-control-bar">
        <div class="vjs-remaining-time vjs-time-controls vjs-control">
            <div class="vjs-remaining-time-display" aria-live="off">
                <span class="vjs-control-text">Remaining Time </span>
                -5:08
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Screenshot

[image]

Comment: Have you taken a screenshot to see if the site is actually loaded and the element is present? Your code should work.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Took a screen shot and the video player was not loaded. How can i make casperjs wait for the video player to load? Added the screenshot above.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PhantomJS (1.x & 2) does not support the `<video>` element.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23703158/screenshot-of-video-element-using-phantomjs) The JavaScript that adds the controls probably detects this and doesn't add any controls, because the video cannot be used.

You will have to find another way to scrape the video duration.